# I want to get the amount of tokens held by a token_account in anchor

Tags: anchor, token-account

I am trying to fetch amount of tokens owned by a token Account in Anchor to verify the number of tokens owned in my Context Struct. I am using anchor_spl::token crate. Can someone tell the structure to fetch the token amount?

Comment: is this as part of an instruction handler or client code written in rust?

Answer (score 1):

To get the amount of tokens held by a token account `user_wallet`:

```
// This line updates the serialized wallet information with the latest changes
user_wallet.reload()?;
// balance is the amount of tokens held
let balance = user_wallet.amount;
```